# space - Is there a minimum safe distance to watch a supernova?

Tags: science-fiction, space, space-travel

Consider that humans now have technology to travel around the galaxy at will.

Hyperspace, warp speed you name it.

There is a distance in which they can watch a supernova as a form of entertainment AND not be harmed in the process? As we do with the sunrise (in terms of experience).
It can be from a planet in another system or a ship.

Edit: consider a special kind of glass-like material capable of filter some radiation. But not all of it. The risk is the same as we taking a sunbath without sunscreen.

Comment: What other technology do they have in terms of things like repairing radiation damage to an organism, shielding, etc.?  And Welcome to Worldbuilding Stack Exchange.  Please also take the [tour] and read over the [FAQ] to get a better idea how this site works.

Comment: Are you the same user behind this other account? https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/72184/cesar-de-barros?tab=profile If so you can request them to be merged

Comment: @L.Dutch 404 when I try the link

Comment: try again with the edited link

Comment: @ZeissIkon well, consider a special kind of glass-like material capable of filter some radiation. But not all of it. The risk is the same as we taking a sunbath without sunscreen.

Comment: @L.Dutch yes! that's me! I thought that account was lost forever! How can I merge them?

Comment: I have contacted a community manager to do the merging

Comment: @MolbOrg 670 lightyears? What the...

Comment: @KeizerHarm it just for cozy flash observation, not an extinction event(the flash, but nebula aka spilled matter is more interesting and hard question),  10x for a second with glasses and cloth won't harm that much and it 1/3 the distance, add 10% tint to a glass and get 1/3 closer. Not sure about spectrum. But okay seems current answer is enough for OP so it all irrelevant

Comment: @KeizerHarm and at a distance it will be days long event(observation), so, exact distance is hard to tell, so I probably should have dug deeper, and more reliable data on duration of the process, and how it evolves, as visible light is secondary emission, so it was just upper estimation, practical distances are shorter. Was a bit misleading, and being mislead by. Let me know u read, I'll delete those comments, should have been done a better job googling or a better memory

Comment: Pretty sure there's a What-If  or one of Randall's NYT columns covering this.  yep,  @Rosspresser  ninja'd me  https://what-if.xkcd.com/73/

Comment: To get your accounts merged, @CesardeBarros, please use [the "contact us" form](/contact) and the appropriate option there — if you have all the relevant information, you should be able to self-merge yourself ^_^

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The actual explosion of a supernova isn't really all that much "entertainment." It's an extremely bright flash. The formation of the nebula might be interesting. But that is a much longer process, starting at months and upwards to 100s of years. And, if you are far enough away as not to be fried by the initial flash, you will need very good telescopes to see the nebula expanding.

So the supernova that produced the crab nebula was observed on Earth in the year 1054. Now, through some very good telescopes, it looks like the following.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crab_Nebula

[image]

It would be pretty interesting to be able to watch that form. The problem is, it took 1000 years to get to that stage. Your audience would need to be quite extremely patient.

But they have hyperspace you say? OK. There is not a single distance to watch from. What you do is arrange to start at a very long distance from the explosion. In this case, about 1000 light years. Then, on observing the initial explosion, you start moving towards it in hyperspace. The idea is, you stop and observe for a short time. Then move closer, stop and observe, move closer, etc. What you wind up with is a "movie." You start with the initial flash, then the "firework" expands out as you move closer. Because hyperspace is faster than light, you adjust things so that over about 30 seconds ship-time (or 4 hours to allow a nice dinner and drinks), you move that 1000 light years closer. That means the apparent expansion takes 30 seconds, because you are travelling "upstream" of the light.

One interesting feature of such a scheme is, you can watch it many times. And from many angles. The light is "crawling" along at light speed. You can hyperspace over and go through the movie as it expands. Since the nebula takes 1000 years to get that big, you have lots of time to watch it many times from many angles.

Comment: Wow. That's perfect.

Comment: Take care to avoid causality violating paradoxes if there are any other people doing the same thing in their FTL ships!!

Comment: Upvoted this answer, time will certainly be an issue, even with the approach strategy. It will probably be a very boring trip for non-scientists. In 1054, the Chinese observed the supernova explosion in the Crab nebula for over a month. All that time the vicinity would be hot and dangerous https://www.nasa.gov/feature/goddard/2017/messier-1-the-crab-nebula

Comment: @JoeBloggs I feel like I recall hearing that there's a way to avoid causality issues with FTL by agreeing on a conventional reference frame to use (like, probably the CMB). Is that right? Do you know if that could work in this case, or does it really depend on how the FTL drive works?

Comment: Assuming relativity is correct, then FTL is unavoidably also a time machine.  If relativity is *not* correct, then who knows?

Comment: If you choose a proper starting point and sublight velocity towards the explosion, you can assemble your "movie" entirely in normal space. For example, to make a 10-minute movie of the Crab nebula forming, you'd start about 967 light years away from the nebula, so you can catch the supernova flash, and then speed up to $\frac{\sqrt{2583233483270399}}{50825520}c = 0.999999999999999806444131652011982848833673483577405269404967507c$ in the direction of the nebula....

Comment: @RossPresser of course by doing so at the end of your 10 minute movie you will have found that everyone roughly stationary to you during that time will have died about 3.5 million years ago, give or take a couple millennia.

Comment: @eps Actually only 967 years. but with ftl being a time machine, so what? Lol

Comment: -1 Not fond of frame-challenges in general; this avoids answering the point of the question -- to see the flash -- in the first line.

Comment: @RossPresser one slight issue is that after watching 1000 years of nebula development, even with near-lightspeed warp drives, your planet will have advanced 1000 years at least by the time you return. Best case there will be a reintegration program awaiting nebula-gazers to catch them up on 1000 years of history. Worst case, post-apocalyptic wasteland and a fearsome predator patiently staring at your landing pod's escape hatch.

Comment: I'm amazed no-one has mentioned the HitchHikers Guide to the Galaxy Here - the bit about the conical ebony bath filled with white sand.

Comment: *"The actual explosion of a supernova isn't really all that much "entertainment." It's an extremely bright flash.*", considering how supernovas can be "entertainment" even when watched from the Earth, you might want to qualify this a bit more. I'm not sure what you mean here... That the remnant would just be a very bright dot from any safe distance for a long time?

Comment: @Quami: Not really, because there's always a nonzero chance that someone who is moving relative to that frame could see something happen in the wrong order and that would have a significant effect. If you picture the 'ladder in a barn' experiment with the barn being in the preferred reference frame you can very easily set up a situation where in one reference frame the ladder passes through the barn with no issues, but in another it crashes into both doors and blows up. Also worth noting that if you *have* a privileged reference frame you're no longer working with relativity.

Comment: "Distance to Earth: 6,523 light years" if you had a FTL ship or drone, you could fly twards the crab nebula and take snapshots as you go ... what we see now is 6,523 years old.  One of the characters in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commonwealth_Saga actually moves to a different part of the galaxy to measure the creation time of a dyson sphere.

Comment: Since you can move FTL, you could back away and watch the explosion several times.

Comment: Presumably the host for dinner is [Max Quordlepleen](https://hitchhikers.fandom.com/wiki/Max_Quordlepleen).

Comment: @JoeBloggs You can visit Milliways as many times as you want without ever meeting yourself. This is, of course, impossible.

Comment: I'm curious how you are going to actually watch a "movie" of something that is 900 light years away.  First of all, you're going to need to make at least 15 hyperspace jumps *per second* to get an effective illusion of movement, but this means you have only 67 milliseconds of telescope time per frame.  I'm pretty sure the pictures you see of nebula typically take many minutes of exposure.

Comment: This is the same way I watch a parade, albeit I travel much more slowly when I want to "fast-forward" or "reverse" the action :)

Answer (score 12):

### Safe distance estimates vary

[50-100 LY](https://earthsky.org/astronomy-essentials/supernove-distance/)
[100 LY](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/232199/what-is-the-safe-distance-to-a-supernova-explosion)
[25 LY](https://gizmodo.com/whats-the-minimum-safe-distance-from-a-supernova-5933548)

Now, if you add a glassy shield, it would depend upon how effective this shield is. Blocking 75% of radiation means only 1 part in 4 harmful radiation gets past your shield - this would allow you to be twice as close since the radiation falls off proportional to distance squared.

If you had a 100% effective shield against ionizing EM radiation, you still have limits unless you could shield against neutrinos since they easily pass through planets and stars and presumably your shield - and there are a massive number of neutrinos in a supernova. So much so, that even though interactions between a neutrino and your body is very rare, you can be killed with a few A.U. of a supernova from neutrinos alone.

Comment: See also https://what-if.xkcd.com/73/ which reveals that *A supernova, seen from as far away as the Sun is from the Earth* is brighter than *The detonation of a hydrogen bomb pressed against your eyeball*

Comment: Obligatory xkcd,yep

Comment: Neutrinos are not something you need to shield against: As the XKCD-What-if details which Ross Presser linked, you'd need to be *inside* a red giant when it goes supernova in order to be killed by neutrino radiation. What you do need to shield against is gamma rays, X-rays, and UV radiation, because that's what a supernova radiates predominantly. Visible light is but a tiny fraction of the power spectrum, which has its maximum far, far off the UV end of the chart.

Comment: @RossPresser You omitted the part about said supernova at 1 AU being brighter than said bomb at eyeball-distance _by nine orders of magnitude._

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica - A non-lethal dose of neutrinos does not mean a safe dose. Just because you are 10 AU away from a supernova (and well outside the star) does not mean that you are safe from neutrino radiation - so even the 100% effective shield against ionizing radiation I mentioned would not really make you safe. You would also be cooked by the infrared or visible light at that distance. I supposed it was obvious to me that you would also have to shield against most of the non-ionizing radiation too.

Comment: The outer layer of a star ready to supernova is a pretty good vacuum - but probably not the best observation location for the supernova :-)

Comment: @GaryWalker The issue about being cooked by the progenitor red giant is precisely why neutrino radiation won't be problem: Assuming you are at a distance where you are neither cooked by the red giant, nor by the supernova explosion itself, you are so far away that the effect from neutrino radiation is negligible. A red giant would turn you into charcoal even if you are on Pluto (>30AU), 13x the lethal dose distance. And since dose drops with distance squared, that's a 169x radiation dose reduction. Nasty, but far from lethal. A nice watching distance is much further out.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica How is 1/169th a reduction sufficient when the original amount is *nine orders of magnitude* greater than an amount already sufficiently powerful to vaporize you along with everything around you?

Comment: @Michael An immediately lethal dose is something like `5 Sv`. If I reduce that dose by a factor of 169, I get `30 mSv`. That's in the range of a full body CT scan (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sievert#Dose_examples_2). So that's definitely the reduction from a lethal dose to a perfectly survivable dose. However, my main point was that *you cannot be as close as 30AU when a supernova goes off, because the red giant would already have incinerated you via "normal" heat radiation*. You need to be much further away to be able to enjoy the firework, and thus won't get any significant neutrino dose.

Comment: @GaryWalker depends; it's pretty up close and personal and most importantly, painless.

Comment: One last comment re: neutrino radiation. I remember reading the XKCD article years ago, and I did additional research at the time. Some other people thought that the neutrino radiation would be considerably more harmful than XKCD estimated. That is why I stated a fuzzy few AU in the first place. Finding those references again would be more effort than I care to spend, and no-one really knows because there are no experiments that can confirm how harmful this form of radiation would be.

Comment: @cmaster What about type 1a supernova?  If you have two white dwarfs merging you could get very close.

Comment: @JasonGeomaat You could get very close to the progenitor star(s), but you'd still need to keep your safety distance to avoid being instantly vaporized by the flash of gamma rays. And 30AU just won't cut it. Remember, Betelgeuse, our closest neighbor red giant is not the brightest star in the sky. But when it goes supernova, it will outshine the moon for a while. Supernovae are extremely energetic events... And type 1a supernovae lack any shielding from a star's shell!